# MySQL InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT secondary column

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am making a system where users can upload any file they want, and not use it to execute any kind of code. As a part of that, I rename every file, and store its original name in a MySQL table. This table contains the id of the user who uploaded it, and a unique id of the upload. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `upload_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `original_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `mime_type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `upload_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This means I will always have a unique combination of user_id and upload_id, and every users first upload has an id of 1. However I want to use a foreign key for the user_Id, so if I delete a user, its uploads would also be deleted. This means I have to do it in InnoDB. How would i go about that, since the above setup only works in MyISAM.

My users table (wich i would get user_id from) looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE `".DATABASE."`.`users` (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `salt` CHAR(128) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What i want is for the uploads table to look like this:

```
user_id  | upload_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 1
2        | 2
2        | 3
1        | 3
```

If that makes sense

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please describe your table relationship?

Comment: there you go, sorry for not being clear

Comment: @DrewPierce glad I did something right :)

Comment: Using auto increment on the upload id column means you will always have a unique combination of user id and upload id even without using both columns as the primary key, or even creating a unique index, because every record will have a different upload id. It will not start over at 1 for each user.

Comment: yes, but i need it to reset for each user.

Comment: Unfortunately for this problem, that is not how auto increment works. But are you sure you need this? The records will still be in ascending order for each user, even if the upload_ids for a user will not be consecutive starting with 1.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No I am not sure i need it, i just like the way that worked in MyISAM and I think the answer is to just do as you say, and have a normal autoincrement on upload_id. It would just make other parts of my code simpler, if i knew those numbers were smaller. But on the other hand, this means I can identify an upload by ID only, and i do not need to include the user ID. will you write your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: your upload_id is not id in database terms... and what you want is not autoincrement - while you want duplicates upload_id.

Comment: @vp_arth please explain what you mean? yes it has duplicate upload_id, but it only has one row per upload, and the combination of user_id and upload_id is always unique. Meaning there is no redundancy, and no need to update multiple rows when changing a value if that is what you are reffereing to

Comment: you can write something like trigger for set upload_id to `max(upload_id)+1 where user_id = ?` but there are multithread issues without whole table locks on each update.

Comment: autoincrement feature is simple sequence generator - it can't to have duplicates

Comment: in MyISAM it could - look at my original solution, it did exactly what i wanted, but did not have foreign keys

Comment: MyISAM uses whole table locks on update :) so it can use(and use) exactly logic described above

Comment: Thank you, I just want something to mimic that behavior in innoDB even if it has to use triggers or anything

Comment: I mention a workaround in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Thank you Rick! Could you post it as an answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

Replace the primary key to a unique index with the two fields. Make the upload_id the primary key and user_id the foreign key then.

Comment: but will that make it auto increment?

Comment: Yes, will be able to your upload_id field.

Comment: You can't do an auto_increment for each user in this way. You need to make it with a trigger or from your application.

Comment: that is basically what I am looking for, a way to get similar results with as much of it being mysql as posible

Comment: Then I recommend you to learn about triggers. I'm not totally sure but I think is the best solution for your case. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for this problem, the auto increment column will not start over at 1 for each user. It will just increment for each added row, regardless of any particular column value.

Edit: displaying my ignorance there, MyISAM tables apparently *will* start over at 1 for each user when a multi-column index this way. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Fortunately, it is probably not necessary for `upload_id` to start at 1 for each user. Using auto increment on that column means you will always have a unique combination of `user_id` and `upload_id` even without using both columns as the primary key, or even creating a unique index, because every record will have a different `upload_id`. You should still be able to implement the cascade delete with this setup.

Comment: yes, but my MyISAM solution did exactly that, and I liked it, even though it wasn't exactly necessary.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but it did what? It reset the upload_id to 1 for each user?

Comment: yes - as explained here: (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Thanks! I actually did not know it could do that. (Obviously.)

Comment: yes it's very handy, but sadly not avaliable in InnoDB, and not posible using 3 columns (which was my next question). So i have to find some other way